# Why is my fixed navbar ontop of my sticky navbar when i coded it in the bottom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to code one sticky bar and one fixed navbar right underneath the sticky with Bootstrap 5. I created one Navbar file with the sticky navbar code in it, and one FixedNav file with my fixed navbar code in it and brought in the Fixed navbar component inside my sticky navbar component. '

[This is what it currently looks like, I want the opposite, yellow Nav on the bottom of white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqsmo.png)

At first, the fixed navbar was overlapping the sticky, and after researching I found out that setting the body with a padding-top:50px would fix it. However, I noticed that the solution only makes the sticky nav bar long enough to show below the fixed navbar, so now the fixed navbar is on top of the sticky navbar. How do I make it so that the sticky navbar is ON TOP of the fixed navbar?

**There is another navbar called LogIn navbar which renders a new navbar once the user is logged in** (wont be focusing on that, in case anyone gets confused with the ternary statement where I bring in the fixed nav component)

```
 import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { logout } from "../store";
import Fixed from "./fixedNav";
import LoginNav from "./LoginNav";

//temporary navBar without loggedIn function/difference
const tempUserId = 1;

const Navbar = ({ handleClick, isLoggedIn }) => (
  <div>
    <div>
      <nav
        className="navbar sticky-top navbar-light bg-light"
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#F0FFFF" }}
      >
        <div>
          <form className="d-flex">
            <input
              className="form-control me-2"
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              aria-label="Search"
            />
            <button className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">
              Search
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="/" className="navbar-brand" />
          Grace Barker
        </div>

        <div>
          <ul className="nav justify-content-end">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">
                Contact Us
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/cart">
                Cart
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <LoginNav handleClick={handleClick} isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
      ) : (
        <Fixed handleClick={handleClick} isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

***FIXED NAVBAR CODE***

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Fixed = ({ handleClick, isLoggedIn }) => (
  <div>
    <nav
      className=" navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg"
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFF8DC" }}
    >
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
          <li className="nav-item ">
            <Link to="/home" className="nav-link ">
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item dropdown">
            <a
              className="nav-link dropdown-toggle "
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              href="/"
              role="button"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              Dogs
            </a>
            <ul className="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a className="dropdown-item " href="/dogs">
                  Available Dogs
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a className="dropdown-item " href="/">
                  Featured Dogs
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/AboutUs" className="nav-link ">
              About Us
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div>
        <ul className="nav justify-content-end">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link active " aria-current="page" href="/users">
              Users
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            {isLoggedIn ? (
              <a
                className="nav-link active "
                aria-current="page"
                href="/home"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                LogOut
              </a>
            ) : (
              <a className="nav-link active " aria-current="page" href="/login">
                Login
              </a>
            )}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
);
export default Fixed;
```

**CSS**

```
body {
```

font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
padding-top: 50px;

}

Answer (score 0):

CSS position fixed is similar to position absolute, it hides everything under it. You can set `z-index` value to it to change its layer order. If you want to show the sticky nav bar just under the fixed one you have to give it a top value same as the height of fixed nav bar.

```
#fixed-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 72px;
    z-index: 100;
}

#sticky-nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 72px; // same as the height of fixed nav bar.
    z-index: 200;
}
```